# VisualStudio 2022 and JSON Folder

Tags: json, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Since some updates, visual studio 2022 when compiling the software, is generating a JSON folder with one file with a strange name
[VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cwM7.png)

This file seems to be a scheme JSON with multiple data inside

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOSoP.png)

Does anyone know how to disable this folder generation?

I tried with VS2019 and no folder appear.
Tried to reinstall VS2022 but problem still there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building C++ solution in VIsual Studio 2022 Community adds a JSON schema folder to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74637613/building-c-solution-in-visual-studio-2022-community-adds-a-json-schema-folder)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in VS2022 that creates this file: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/JSON-Schema-being-written-to-solution-fo/10158717?ref=native&refTime=1670770713838&refUserId=0df77896-7743-4fe4-b1b6-e8ab3bf9f21b