# Building C++ solution in VIsual Studio 2022 Community adds a JSON schema folder to project

Tags: c++, json, schema, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 Community version 17.4.2

Visual Studio recently updated and now whenever I build my solution a folder appears that contains a massive JSON Schema at `[Solution Folder]/JSON/Schemas/Catalog/https%003A%002F%002Fgo.microsoft.com%002Ffwlink%002F%003Flinkid%003D835884` of 600 entries and over 4000 lines.

This is causing havoc with my version control. How do I prevent this file from being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/JSON-Schema-being-written-to-solution-fo/10158717?ref=native&refTime=1670770713838&refUserId=0df77896-7743-4fe4-b1b6-e8ab3bf9f21b) internal to Visual Studio.

The [fix is live](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.4.5). Update to Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.5 or later.

Comment: Turns out it was a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/JSON-Schema-being-written-to-solution-fo/10158717?port=1025&fsid=1dbe4359-3d8f-4e4b-9bb5-50cfb580c24e&ref=native&refTime=1670770713838&refUserId=0df77896-7743-4fe4-b1b6-e8ab3bf9f21b) internal to Visual Studio.

Comment: Im facing the same issue with C# projects only

Comment: @Mightywill The issue has a fix and is pending release. See the linked bug report.